# How to check if array is already sorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

so how to make such logic

```
int[] arr = {2, 5, 3};

if (/* arr is sorted */)
    ....
else 
    ...
```

Its bad that method Array.sort is void

Comment: What are you going to do if the array is not sorted?

Comment: You have to write your own logic. Iterate over the array, and test each element with the next element.

Comment: nothing, i just need somehow check if arr is sorted or not

Comment: only iteration can help here?

Comment: How else would you check to see if the array were sorted?

Comment: Arrays.sort sorts the array. It doesn't check whether an array is sorted or not.

Answer (score 49):

You don't need to sort your array to check if it's sorted. Loop over each consecutive pair of elements and check if the first is less than the second; if you find a pair for which this isn't true, the array is not sorted.

```
boolean sorted = true;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
        sorted = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: loop is okey but isnt here something else faster, for example equal our arr with sorted arr

Comment: @OxomHuK How do you find sorted array?

Comment: @OxomHuK If by "faster" you mean more efficient: no.

Comment: It's impossible to be faster. You have to look at all the elements at least once, obviously. How else can you be share if you don't look at them all?

Comment: @arshajii, just for completeness, what about checking for downward sorted array too?

Comment: @OxomHuK You can put all of this in a function and just call that. Less code doesn't always mean better.

Comment: @You can use `sorted = sorted && (arr[i] > arr[i+1])`

Comment: @Elist Why would you use that? You would lose the short-circuiting ability.

Comment: Whoever down voted was probably jealous. Great answer. Simple and efficient.

Comment: Your'e right: `if(!(sorted = sorted && (arr[i] > arr[i+1]))) break;` maintains short-circuit

Comment: And why not `for (int i : arr)`?

Comment: @Elist That only allows you to access one element of the array per iteration, we need to access two.

Comment: It wasn't me to downvote, but it's pretty much justifiable. You don't need to implement such logic yourself, when you have proper RTL support, namely `clone`, `Arrays.sort` and `equals` handy.

Answer (score 13):

```
public static <T>
boolean isArraySorted(T[] elements, Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
  int n = elements.length;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (cmp.compare(elements[i-1], elements[i]) > 0) { return false; }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 Use the generics... Very good toy, but, I believe, I have never needed to ask if an array is already sorted.

Comment: This is great, you come up with it on the fly or have it stashed away somewhere lol? I hope the latter for my fragile ego, good job. +1

Comment: Extracting length is really unnecessary, though, unless interpreting.

Comment: Note that this will not work with the OP's example, since he wants to check an array of primitives. In an ideal world, one would have an analogous method for each primitive array type.

Comment: @arshajii, Good point.  I assumed that was a throwaway example, but to make it truly generic I'd have to use `java.lang.reflect.Array` along with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` which would defeat all the generic safety checks you get from the compiler.  I think overloading for primitive types is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i + 1] < a[i]) {
            return false;
        };
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: should be arr.length, not arr.length()

Answer (score 2):

Well you can check it in O(n) worst case linear time.
A non-sorted array (assuming you mean sorting in ascending order) will have a trip point. That is at some point arr[i] > arr[i+1]

All you need to do is

```
boolean is_array_sorted(int arr[]) {
  for(int i=0; i < arr.len-1; i++) {
    if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
       return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Just change the `>` to `<` if your array sort is supposed to be descending order

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version:

```
[0,1,2,3,4].reduce((a,v) => (a!==false) && (a <= v) ? v : false, -Infinity)
[4,3,1,2,0].reduce((a,v) => (a!==false) && (a >= v) ? v : false, +Infinity)
```

Be careful, as in some cases it isn't effective because it will loop through entire array without breaking prematurely.

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example)

Comment: Very helpful answer, HOWEVER, wrong programming language. Java is not the same as javascript.

Comment: @JackGiffin, Java got stream right, you can use reduce() just fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.every`

```
let isSorted = array.every((v, i) => (i === 0 || v <= array[i - 1]))
  || array.every((v, i) => (i === 0 || v >= array[i - 1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isArraySorted(arr) {
    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if (arr[i+1] && (arr[i+1] > arr[i])) {
            continue;
        } else if(arr[i+1] && (arr[i+1] < arr[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of [the generics version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18111289/918858) by [Mike Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20394/mike-samuel) but using `Comparable<T>` instead of `Comparator<T>`:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(T[] elements) {
    int n = elements.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (elements[i - 1].compareTo(elements[i]) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```