# Java method to confirm the sorting works

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I have an array of 100 ints (from 0 to 99) and I implement a Comparable interface. My task now is to confirm that sorting works (even though I know it does). My code is:

```
public static boolean confirmSorting(Guppy[] sortedArrayOfGuppies) {
    boolean confirmed = false;
    int maximumID = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Guppy guppy : sortedArrayOfGuppies) {
        if (guppy.getIdentificationNumber() < maximumID) {
            maximumID = guppy.getIdentificationNumber();
            confirmed = true;
        }
    }
    return confirmed;
}
```

But it returns true even for unsorted arrays. How do I make sure that iterate through **every single object** in my array?

Unfortunately, the solution proposed in [How to check if array is already sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111231/how-to-check-if-array-is-already-sorted) doesn't work, not all ints are unique (some are the same)

Comment: It does iterate through the whole array; the problem is that you set `confirmed = true` when you find any item that's smaller than the previous one, instead of checking that they all are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume they are in sorted order first.  Then return as soon as you find ones that aren't.  No need to keep checking upon encountering the first failure.  This does a simple verification and does not print any information.  It returns `true` if sorted in ascending order and `false` otherwise. It also presumes the id number is an `int`.

```
public static boolean confirmSorting(Guppy[] sortedArrayOfGuppies) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArrayOfGuppies.length-1; i++) {
        int id1 = sortedArrayOfGuppies[i].getIdentificationNumber();
        int id2 = sortedArrayOfGuppies[i+1].getIdentificationNumber();
        if (id1 > id2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that you may want to pass in a `comparator` or `flag` so you can verify both ascending and descending sorts.

Comment: Code has same 3 errors as the question code: 1) If the *next* value is **greater than** the highest value seen so far (which means values are in ascending order), the code immediately returns `false` indicating that values are not sorted, the exact opposite of what is supposedly being checked. --- 2) `maximumID` is never updated. Well, except right before returning `false`, so it doesn't matter. --- 3) With `maximumID = Integer.MAX_VALUE`, a check for `x > maximumID` can never be true.

Comment: I fixed it.  It can serve as example for the OP.

Comment: I think it works now, thanks

Comment: Yup, the code now matched the answers in the duplicate links.