# Sorting Array of strings is returning incorrect result(s)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> - I want to check if an array of strings is strictly in ascending order or not.

**For example**

> ["20", "1000"] => should return true

> ["1000", "20"] => should return false

I'm trying to do:

```
["20", "1000"].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
```

However, this returns `["1000", "20"]`

I've even used `_.sortBy(["20", "1000"])` same result.

**Complete code:**

```
const isAscendingOrder = (arr) => {
  const temp = [...arr]

  const sortedArr = _.sortBy(temp)

  return sortedArr.toString() === arr.toString()
}
```

What am i missing? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That's the correct result for strings.  If you want to sort them as numbers, parse them to numbers.

Comment: Why are you using localeCompare for this? The inputs are strings and you want to sort by numerical order so you would need to parseInt instead if they're all whole numbers

Comment: This should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111231/how-to-check-if-array-is-already-sorted

Comment: @Bz068 that works if the array has numbers which is understandable. I have an array of strings. I think i could run into `parseInt(a)-parseInt(b)` in my comparator.

Comment: Have you seen the [numeric sorting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#numeric_sorting) option for `localeCompare()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
const isAscendingOrder = (arr) => {
    const temp = [...arr]
    const arrSort = temp.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    return JSON.stringify(arrSort) === JSON.stringify(arr)

}

console.log(isAscendingOrder(['1000', '2', '4', '1', '6'])) // return falce
console.log(isAscendingOrder(['1', '2', '4', '6'])) // return true
```