# Comparing Elements Values In An Array, and returning Boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

Can anyone help I am nearly there I can get the code to return true for the first 2 test below, but not return false for the next 2 tests, what I need to do is to check that all the numbers in the array are in ascending order so every element number is greater than the last for the length of the array. Any ideas? Kind regards Jon.

```
 Test.expect(inAscOrder([1, 2, 4, 7, 19])
 Test.expect(inAscOrder([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
 Test.expect(!inAscOrder([1, 6, 10, 18, 2, 4, 20])
 Test.expect(!inAscOrder([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

function inAscOrder(arr) {

let result = false;

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
for (let k = 0; k <= arr.length; k++) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[k+1]) {
     result = true;
            
    } 
   }
  }
```

return result;
}

Comment: You were close, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18111261/10362872).

Comment: you can use functional way to make life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to answer

```
function inAscOrder(arr) {
    let result = true;

    for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            result = false;
            break;   
        }
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Armand I went down the single for loop route first of all and all I way missing was knowing how to compare the current iteration of the array i to the next element using i+1 in [ ]. Awesome thank you for your help much appreciated kind regards Jon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You can use the functional way instead.

```js
const inAscOrder = arr => arr.slice(1).every((elem,i) => elem > arr[i]);
console.log(inAscOrder([1,2,5]));
```

Comment: This is returning false for given input

Comment: @Mohitkumar editted the answer, now passes all testt

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to compare two arrays, is to convert them to a strings and then compare the strings.

```js
const isAscending = (arr) => arr.join("") == arr.sort((a, b) => a - b).join("");

console.log(isAscending([1, 2, 4, 7, 19]));
console.log(isAscending([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(isAscending([1, 6, 10, 18, 2, 4, 20]));
console.log(isAscending([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

For every element in the array, return true if it's the first element or it's greater than the previous element.

```js
const isAscending = (arr) => arr.every((el, i, arr) => i === 0 || el > arr[i - 1]);

console.log(isAscending([1, 2, 4, 7, 19]));
console.log(isAscending([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(isAscending([1, 6, 10, 18, 2, 4, 20]));
console.log(!isAscending([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
```